# ASP.NET: Web Development Choices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have been learning to develop websites using ASP.NET MVC 2 for work... and previous to this, I had never developed within an .NET environment before. Since I jumped right into using MVC, I honestly have no idea how else to develop websites with ASP.NET.

I've heard about "WebForms" here and there, but don't really get the difference. But, beyond that, what other means of web development is there with ASP.NET?

It's all very backwards, I know... but if you can just humor me and perhaps list the different ways of utilizing C# to develop great web applications, that would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is the platform for developing .NET web applications.

Sitting on top of that platform is two technologies to choose from:

- ASP.NET Web Forms
- ASP.NET MVC

Web Forms uses WinForms-style development - drag/drop, event handlers, page lifecycle, statefulness with ViewState - all things evil in my opinion.

MVC as you know has no page lifecycle, no event handlers, no server controls (you can, but not recommended/required), no ViewState.

Don't really know what else i can say without going into too much detail.

Both technologies will be continued to be supported/enhanced.

But since your already versed in ASP.NET MVC - i seen no benefit in learning Web Forms. It would be a step back if anything.

As for this statement:

> just humor me and perhaps list the different ways of utilizing C# to develop great web applications

That's a bit too broad/subjective.

What is "great"? Well performing? Looks good? Maintainable? All of the above?

No doubt - MVC will do a better job at *most* things than Web Forms.

Only feasible choice for a Web Forms app might be a intranet application where tons of complex grids/controls are required, and things like SEO/AJAX is not required.

Everything else should be done in MVC IMO.